# What will be the work if somehow displacement becomes zero?

Tags: work, displacement

Suppose an object (aeroplane be better) having 1m/s² acceleration, started its journey from north pole towards south pole. Crossing south pole it reached north pole again.

So, here displacement is 0 meter (as the initial point and the final point are the same). If we neglect the frictional force of air... can we say **there is no work done by the force which made the object accelerated?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not zero, because the work done by a force is defined by a line integral. The work done by the force that accelerated the object is

$$W=\int_{\vec{r}_0}^{\vec{r}_f}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r},$$

being $\vec{r}_0$ the point where the force began to act, and $\vec{r}_f$ the point where it stopped being applied. If the force is constant (you said that the acceleration is, for example, $1 \text{m/s}^2$) and parallel to the displacement, the work would be $W=F\cdot d$, being $d$ the lenght of the path followed while the force was being applied.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of work.`the work done by a conservative force is path independent ,and work by nonconservative is path dependent.so the work done need not be always  zero.

Comment: So...here...what type of work is it? Reply please